# javascript: call a C++ library from javascript code inside both the browser and node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Is there a way to call a c++ library from javascript code inside both a browser and node.js? Ideally, the code to invoke a function call in the library is the same for both cases. It's acceptable if the approach only supports Chrome for a browser. I've found approaches that support either the browser or node.js, but not both. Thanks.

Edit: To clarify, I have a pure javascript codebase that runs both server-side (node) and client-side (browser) and I want the c++ library to be callable from this codebase for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

With NaCl its possible to [message a C++ extention with javascript](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/message-system). This requires you to basically develop a chrome extenstion/app, I doubt you can access the C++ library from code outside of the extension however, unless you implement said feature.

On node you can [wrap c++ objects](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects), but these approaches are different.

If you wanted to have a uniform way to do this you could develop a middleware to handle that, but thats a project in its own.